# Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates, how to tell which is ingoing and which is outgoing?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems

The Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates in case of Schwarzschild metric are defined as

\begin{align}
u&=t-r^*\\
v&=t+r^*
\end{align}

where $$r^*=r+2GM\ln\left|\frac{r}{2GM}-1\right|$$

The question is that how to understand which one is ingoing and which one is outgoing. Why $v$ is ingoing and $u$ is outgoing?

Answer (score 3):

$du,dv$ are light-like, i.e. they could, in principle, be viewed as some affine parameters of some light-rays. However, we will focus (in the spirit of the usual coordinate-nature analysis) on what is the nature of either $u,v$ constant. I.e., we want to know what is the nature of $u,v$ constant hypersurfaces and derive the nomenclature from this.

We will take it as fact that u,v can be viewed as parametrizing *some* light congruence.

Now the question is what is the nature of congruence parametrized by $u,v$. Let us consider some finite $t=t_0$ and $r_*=r_0$. If we are investigating $u,v$ constant hypersurfaces, then $t>t_0$ means surely $r_*>r_0$ for $u=t-r_*$ constant. I.e., the $u=const.$ surface is farther out at a later time. Hence, the lightcone is interpreted as  *outgoing* with respect to the centre $r_*=0$ for $u=$const. and we call the respective Finkelstein coordinate the outgoing coordinate.

The opposite is true for $v=t+r_*$. $t>t_0$ means surely $r_*<r_0$ for $v=$ const., or that for $v$ constant we have a lightcone *ingoing* with respect to the centre $r_*=0$.

Comment: I think Void meant "ingoing" in the last sentence.